# how to set in vector float x y coordinates

Tags: java, android, vector, bullet-physics

i am use eclipse java android i am try to projectile trajectory in my game like angry birds example here  http://blog.gemserk.com/2012/07/03/drawing-a-projectile-trajectory-like-angry-birds-using-libgdx/

this is my code error   - x cannot be resolved or is 
     not a field
- y cannot be resolved or is 
     not a field

how to solve this problem

```
class ProjectileEquation {

    public float gravity;  
    public Vector<E> startVelocity = new Vector<E>();  
    public Vector<E> startPoint = new Vector<E>();  



    public float getX(float t) {  
        return startVelocity.x * t + startPoint.x;  
    }  

    public float getY(float t) {  
        return 0.5f * gravity * t * t + startVelocity.y * t + startPoint.y;  
    }  

}
```

Comment: What Vector class are you using?

Comment: Vector<E> class

Comment: I was expecting something more like "com.somelibrary.Vector" or "I wrote it myself".

Comment: java.util.Vector;

Comment: The page you point to is not using Vector but instead using Vector2.

Answer (score 1):

It is at it says, java.util.Vector does not a field named x or y. It is probably not the class you want to be using here. java.util.Vector is close to ArrayList and is meant to store a list of items in a thread-safe manner. So I recommend writing you own vector class instead.

Here is an example

```
public class Vector2f {
    public float x;
    public float y;
}
```

You should be able to use this in you code instead.

Comment: sorry sar, but this vector not allow a float x y

Comment: @user5547340 What do you mean by not allow?

Comment: i try other code  error like   he method set(int, E) in the type Vector<E> is not applicable for the arguments (float, float)

Comment: @user5547340 You should try to understand what the code is doing rather than just blindly copying it. Also it's directly telling you what's wrong.